# PostGIS values within XYZ viewport in OpenLayers

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2

I have an XYZ server where I get my maptiles.

Now, when the user is at zoom level 1 ( closest). I want it to execute a command that gets the current viewport from the map and Queries my PostGIS database to get the geometry points that are contained within that viewport.

How could this get done and what is the best way to display this data as fast as possible on the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the `map.getExtent()` together with `map.events.register('moveend')` - And then parsing the results to the SQL and use postgis method `ST_Within` might work for me! Yet to be tested in full!